# Проблема с импортом кастомных записей

Tags: wordpress-плагины, импорт, polylang

Всем привет!
Использую плагины Polylang + WP All Import. Имеем на сайте 2 языка. Кастомные записи.
Нужно наладить импорт записей с переводами.
Нет понимания, как правильно засинхронизировать записи, чтобы они импортировались уже синхронизированные между собою по языкам.